# Tying text-box to responsive canvas with image

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm creating a quote-generator page which is also responsive. Here's the [link to quote-generator](http://www.paolo-caponeri.ga/quote-machine/index.html). That's a canvas that dynamically resizes as the page gets smaller or bigger while keeping the image ratio fixed.

What I'd like to do is for the text to follow the image in staying in the center. I'm not trying to get a piece of code that does it, but even if you have the logic behind it, then I can figure how to do it, because at the moment I'm really not sure where to start from.

Thank you.

Comment: This is cool! .But i have never created anything like that  so why don't you inspect its source code to get started? My guess is that they have hooked onto window resize event from where they calculate new positions

Answer (score 0):

In this case, put both of that `<canvas>` and the `<div>` preceding it into one higher`<div>` and then you just have to set the relative width and height of the highest div to percentages. Something like this:

```
<div id="higherDiv" style="width: 80%, height: 80%">
     <canvas>...</canvas>
     <div>...</div>
</div>
```

In this way you get a scalable top container relative to user's screen dimensions. If the percentages don't work, you can try this new relative dimensions introduced in >HTML5, here: https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units